# visual studio development server automatically redirects to default port with machine ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webdev.webserver

This is a weird issue I have been facing for a couple of days now. When I run my ASP.Net web app from visual studio 2010, it starts the dev server and opens IE. I can see the correct URL getting formed (`ex: http://localhost:53990/index.aspx`). 
But then it redirects to "`http://my-machine-ip`". I can see the dev server process (webdev) in task manager. If I browse the above URL in a separate IE instance, manually, I still get the same behavior.

This problem comes in chrome as well, but works properly in Firefox.

Since it was working in FF, I ignored it, but now an increasing number of my colleagues have started facing the exact same issue. Tried searching for a solution on Google and stackoverflow, but couldn't find any.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Would be great if I can get any help/pointers with this issue. Please let me know if you need more details.

PS: I am coding in c#, not sure if it matters but thought I should specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue and resolved by following steps:->

1. Open IE
2. Go to Internet Option ->Connections
3. Click on Lan Settings
4. Uncheck Automatic detect settings check box.
5. Clear all browser cache/history
6. Try and browse the site now. You should be able to view your site

Since Chrome uses IE settings, this solution should work for Chrome too.